Solana RPC node falling behind
Hello guys no matter what i try i cant keep up in network, it says we are falling behind, i download latest snapshot which makes us only 1900 slots behind and we are supposed to gain slots and instead we are falling behind and lossing apprx. -2 slots/s, i believe my hardware is enough AMD EPYC 9454P with 48 cores, 512 GB memory and 2x 2TB nvme disks, i use one for accounts and the other one for everything else, with 10Gbit/s bandwidth, on older machine i was able to get "gaining slots" pretty ofter however it was eventually still falling behind but at much slower rate than with this new server
im currently using these flags, i tried many different ones as well when i tried to use known validators i couldnt find rpc nodes and also only this entrypoint works well for me, others are either unreachable or have high ping. but i still greatly appreciate any suggestions, im new to this so im still learning, thank you for responses and understanding, ps: im using 3rd party script to fetch snapshots



So i have no idea why it suddenly started to work, i left it process all night and we were about 30 000 slots behind but i noticed that the average slots was gaining by 0.2 slots/s so i decided to download new snapshots which got us to about 1000slots behind but we were still gaining 0.2 slots/s so i left it for hours and it finally caught up, i have no idea what changed, i think nothing..
IMPORTANT EDIT: My issue was that i wasnt using Agave version of validator, so i switched to that one
